# How to implement a Directory chooser in spring-boot using thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot app that returns a Thymeleaf form.

I would like to add a button that will let the user to choose a directory and get the directory path as a String (or as a File). I do not care about the content of the directory.

My Thymeleaf .html file looks like this:

```
    <div>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
            <table>
                <tr><td>File to upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li th:each="file : ${files}">
                <a th:href="${file}" th:text="${file}" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And my controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/")
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename());

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Is it possible to be implemented as a Spring Boot - Thymeleaf App?

Comment: The input type will have a button to select a file. Selecting a directory is not possible nor will that have any meaning on the server side.

Comment: I just want from the user to provide a directory path. I think the most user-friendly way is to use a browse button instead of asking them to copy-paste it as a plain text. On top of that, the server will run locally, so if I have the path I will be able to run some commands on that directory. So I am wondering how could I get the path of a user's directory

Comment: You cannot, at least not with the input type `file`. Also that basically has nothing to do with Spirng Boot or Thymeleaf but rather with what that input type represents.

Comment: is there another way? what input type should I use instead of `file`?

Comment: There isn't, as you aren't allowed to access a file system in that way (security reasons). You could let users select a file in the directory and then strip that on the server and only use the path.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "WebKitDirectory" to the input type file to get option to select folder.
refer addition to your code

```
<tr><td>File to upload:<input type="file" name="file" WebKitDirectory /></td></tr>
```

you can read and try example from below link

WebKitDirectory: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory

Note: above does not work with Android Mozilla on mobile.